# In R, if I want to bring down the previous command without overwriting what I've already written, how can I do this?

Tags: r, rstudio

I know that pressing the up arrow key brings down the previous command in R. In doing so, however, it overwrites anything that has already been typed on the command line. So for instance, if I want to define an object using a long command I've just executed, I have to press the up-arrow then either click or navigate via arrow keys *all the way back to the beginning* of the command to add in my object_name <- [command I've just brought down].

Is there anyway to bring down the previous command to wherever my cursor is, rather than having it overwrite the entire command line?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Press the `Home` key instead of `Left`+`Left`+`Left`+`Left`+`...`+`Left`?

Comment: I think most IDEs don't have an easy shortcut for "insert previous command at my current cursor (without interrupting text to the left)", but I might be wrong there. Regardless, I think it's not difficult to do either (a) `object_name <-`, then `[Shift-Home][Cut][Up][Home][Paste]`, or (b) `[Up][Home]object_name <- [End][Enter]`.